# Remote access and local access same hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname

I have a server in a clients network, seperated from theirs with a router/firewall, the intention is to have this server available through one hostname (example.com)

My idea is to have (at least) a DNS server in the outside, to have outside (out of the clients' network) access the internal server. The problem would at that point be the internal client (PC A)

[image: example]

My question: What would I have to do to make something like this work? Is it even possible or already done? The goal is to not have to change *anything* on either PC A or PC B, while both should access the same "internal server" while surfing to "example.com"

Perhaps adding logic to the DNS server would work (Detect the external IP of internal client [PC A] is the same as the IP for example.com -> Give the local IP as reply?)

Anyhow: Thanks for helping me think on this!

Comment: Split DNS suggestion below is correct, don't use example.com though, remote.example.com (or similar) will be much easier.

Comment: Yeah, our idea was to have a clientname.example.com solution, like dyndns in a way, because most clients will have dynamic IP's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically talking about a split-DNS where some hosts are handled by an internal DNs and some by the external.  this can be done by runnig a small DNS server inside the firewall with the local IP of the server.  That DNs shoudl then forward all other requests to the "real" dns.

If the router has DNS built in, you could add the entry there.

Another option would be a host file entry on the inside PCs that points to the server.  All other requests would go to DNS (but you mentioned not wanting to touch the PCs.).

\\uSlackr

Comment: Unfortunately both changing the hosts file and changing the router would change the clients' network (or computer), which we're trying to avoid. At the very least, we're trying to give the client the flexibility of (e.g.) changing ISP's without having to inform us (so we can put a new router or similar), we shouldn't have the need to configure the client computer or router in any way (if at all possible of course)

Comment: If you use an internal DNS and have the clients point to it, how would that prevent them from changing ISPs without telling you?  Problem is you are eliminating possible (maybe all) solutions.  DNS resolution is between the client and the DNS server.  You have to intercept or break it to change the results.

Comment: We didn't intend to put hardware in the client network in any way, preferably, this would all work externally, now, to clarify: Would it be possible to have an external DNS server internal IP's?

Answer (score -1):

OP wants to do this without modifying client machines, OR the network they are on.

The only way I know of to achieve this is to add your internal IP address to an external DNS server. You can register a domain with a hosting provider, make an A record to redirect requests to your-domain.com to your-IP-address. This will only resolve if you happen to be on its internal network. You can then use a reverse proxy to redirect requests to the machine to various services by their exposed ports, otherwise you'll have to type your-domain.com:8081 for any services not running on port 80 or 443

This method does pose a security vulnerability, though. It's better to hide or obfuscate the path to your machine. You could use Cloudflare Zero Trust tunnels, however while the IP address is hidden, traffic does leave the local network, which poses its own risks, creates latency, and is just not what OP wants.

There must be a way to achieve both simultaneously... I'll let you know when I find it.